# RadWindow icon not visible in taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radwindow

Im use telerik RadWindow and I dony see the icon of the window in the task bar.

I set the header of the window:

```
Header="My Window"
```

And I set the Icon Template:

```
<telerik:RadWindow.IconTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Image Source="../planet.ico"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</teleik:RadWindow.IconTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the icon for MinimizeIconUrl, your problem must be solved